# sleep mode not start when turn down screen

Tags: kernel, amdgpu, nomodeset

I have problem of black screen means when I start sleep mode then screen light not get of . sleep mode not start when turn down screen
the Ubuntu release/version

```
  Distributor ID:   Ubuntu
  Description:  Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
 Release:   22.04
 Codename:  jammy
```

hardware is

```
 Terminal: gnome-terminal 
 Intel CPU: Intel i5-8250U (8) @ 3.400GHz 
GPU: Intel UHD Graphics 620 
 GPU: AMD ATI Radeon R7 M260/M265 / M340/M360 / M440/M445 / 
  530/535 / 620/625 Mobile
```

Comment: `nomodeset` is intended as a **temporary** workaround until the proper proprietary graphics drivers are installed. Not applicable to AMD graphics and you shouldn't be messing with amdgpu.

Comment: then why I have screen problem and I can fix it

Comment: We don't know what problem you actually have since you turned this into and X-Y problem, i.e., you're asking about what you think is a solution instead of the actual problem. A proper question would include a description of the problem, the hardware specifications and Ubuntu release/version.

Comment: Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release: 22.04
Codename: jammy hardware dell inspiron 5570 . I have problem is sleep mode not start when turn down screen and when I shut down and open again then only keyboard light is on

Comment: 1. Comments are for us to ask you for additional information or clarification. Please [edit] the question to add such info, not comments. 2. When asked about hardware specifications please provide hardware specifications (in this case particularly the graphics), not a brand/model that can come with many different configurations and options.